# JavaScript, getElementById from local storage returns blank page with element on it

Tags: javascript, local-storage, capacitor

I'm trying to get data from `localStorage`, but my whole app becomes a blank screen with the data I'm trying to retrieve at the top of it.

I was reading online that I should add `return false;` to the function where I'm getting the data, but it doesn't help.

Code:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('test',
JSON.stringify({ scoreId: window.scoreId, streak: 0, testMe: 'testing, testing'})
);

const retrieveStreak = () => {
const test = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('test'));
const testStreak = document.getElementById('root').textContent = test.testMe;
console.log(testStreak);
return false;
}
```

Otherwise the data is saving successfully, and when retrieving it I also get it printed out in `console.log`, but the issue is that my whole app goes blank.

Comment: What exactly is element with `root` ID?

Comment: "but my whole app goes blank screen where at top of it I get data im trying to retrieve." — Umm. So maybe you don't want to set the `textContent` of `root` to that value. Sounds like it is just doing what you are telling it to do.

Comment: <div id="root"></div>   from guide I found on YouTube they declare div id from index.html, that's why I wrote 'root' there, what should I do differently in order to be able to access locally stored data without it being returned to a blank page?

Comment: The code you present doesn't include `retrieveStreak();` at the end, so the function isn't called, which would mean the `#root` element will stay empty. Adding that in makes your example work as expected for me.

Comment: I'm calling retrieveStreak(); in another function, it works for me as well... though for some reason app goes blank with testStreak being printed at top of it

Answer (score 0):

Deleted
`document.getElementById('root').textContent =`
from the code and now it works as expected

Thank Quentin for the tip

```
window.localStorage.setItem('test',
JSON.stringify({ scoreId: window.scoreId, streak: 0, testMe: 'testing, testing'})
);

const retrieveStreak = () => {
const test = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('test'));
const testStreak = document.getElementById('root').textContent = test.testMe;
console.log(testStreak);
return false;
}
```